# Append MIDI files using bytearray in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript, arrays, midi

I need to append MIDI files: leave header (same for all files) and other meta information, just copy music/score part.
I already have MIDI files in appropriate bytearrays, as I guessed I need to use writeBytes, but unfortunately couldn't find which bytes I need to take and copy.
Something like this:

```
 var newFileBytes:ByteArray=new ByteArray();
 newFileBytes.writeBytes(firstMIDIBytes);
 newFileBytes.writeBytes(secondMIDIBytes,8);
```

Works only partially, file is playable; first part fully and second - only some notes (then player hangs out)

To say truth byteArrays aren't my strong side, as the MIDI file structure.
Can you suggest how to solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean to append the midi files? That's not the same thing as merging them...

Comment: IMHO you are right, it's more append then merge. I just edited question in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, you probably mean to append these files, not merge them. Assuming that to be the case, you can't simply slap the data from the second file to the end of the first. As the MIDI protocol is bandwidth-optimized, it makes a number of assumptions regarding the streaming of events. These behaviors mean that you must take special care when appending MIDI data.

MIDI files can (and usually) use running status, which means that an even may omit the status byte, in which case the event should use the status byte of the previous event. This may not be the cause of your problems, but are you absolutely sure that you are only parsing raw MIDI data, and not the file headers and such? If this were the case, all sorts of weird data would be erroneously interpreted as valid MIDI events.

Events in MIDI files use relative offsets to the previous event in the sequence. The way that this is calculated is a bit complicated, but it involves a few properties (such as tempo, number of pulses/sec, etc) which are defined in the MIDI file header. If you stripped these events, and the properties are different for the second file, then the timing of these events will be wrong.

Basically, the only safe way to append the two MIDI files is to play them through a sequencer and re-write them to a new stream. Appending the byte arrays will probably be the cause of many mysterious bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I mean that all "non musical" data is the same, tempo, pulses etc. Just imagine MIDIs are actually part of one song, so need to copy only "musical data" from one file to another, all other data is the same.
In this case IMHO if I know entry point for the MIDI from which I need to copy (I got 8bit position cause as I know MThd chunck finish there and actual MTrk chunk begins) and the end point (where tracks data is finished) for the MIDI where I want to paste this data, I can somehow merge this files.
I might be wrong and thinking like I'm copy/pasting as in XML files.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of a MIDI file doesn't allow you to just "append" more data to it, for the following reasons:

1. Each track ends with an End of Track event, rendering all notes after that event meaningless.
2. Each track header chunk defines the size of the data that follows. Even if you append new data, any reader will only read [size] bytes before it starts looking for a new track.
3. A MIDI file defines how many tracks are present in the file, so even if you appended the byte array of a single MIDI track, unless you also update the track count of the header data, any reader would simply ignore the track you added.

If you add data to a MIDI file, you need to make sure the structural integrity of the file format is maintained. Simply appending data does not accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as I see only solution is to convert MIDI files to ex: MusicXML "append" them and convert final file to MIDI.

Comment: Please consider accepting my or Nik's answer if they answered your question.